# How to reference parent's parameter in child function argument?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, parameters, angular6

In `Angular 6.0.7`, I have a parent class `wj-flex-grid-parent.class.ts`. It has the parameter `public m_wjcGridXlsx = wjcGrid.xlsx;` I'm able to successfully reference this parameter from my child component using `this.m_wjcGridXlsx`.

One function in the child component is still giving me problems when trying to reference `m_wjcGridXlsx` in its argument:

```
public _exportFormatItem(args: m_wjcGridXlsx.XlsxFormatItemEventArgs) {
...
}
```

`this.m_wjcGridXlsx` gets highlighed by intellisense and says **Cannot find namespace 'm_wjcGridXlsx'**. How can I reference the `m_wjcGridXlsx` parameter here in the `arg`? I've tried preappending `this.` and `self.` to no avail.

**Parent Component:**

```
import { OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as wjcGridXlsx from 'wijmo/wijmo.grid.xlsx';
   
export class WjFlexGridParent implements OnInit
{    
    
    public m_wjcGridXlsx = wjcGridXlsx;    // the parameter giving me problems

...
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { WjFlexGridParent } from '../fw/wijmo/wj-flex-grid-parent.class';

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...']
  })

  export class ChildComponent extends WjFlexGridParent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

    randomFunction() {  
     // this works, m_wjcGridXlsx is recognized:
     this.m_wjcGridXlsx.FlexGridXlsxConverter.saveAsync(this.m_grid, { includeColumnHeaders: true, includeCellStyles: false, formatItem: null }, strFileName);
    }


    // this doesn't work, m_wjcGridXlsx is not recognized:
    public _exportFormatItem(args: m_wjcGridXlsx.XlsxFormatItemEventArgs) { 
       ...
    }

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ViewChild,
  EventEmitter, HostListener
} from '@angular/core';
import { WjFlexGridParent } from '../fw/wijmo/wj-flex-grid-parent.class';

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...']
})
export class ChildComponent extends WjFlexGridParent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  _exportFormatItem(args: m_wjcGridXlsx.XlsxFormatItemEventArgs) {}
}
```

You are using an undeclared identifier, `m_wjcGridXlsx`. There is simply nothing named `m_wjcGridXlsx` in scope. You have indeed inherited a property named `m_wjcGridXlsx` from `WjFlexGridParent`, but, as with any property, you must qualify, in this case with either `this` or `super`.

However, if we write

```
_exportFormatItem(args: this.m_wjcGridXlsx.XlsxFormatItemEventArgs) {}
```

`this.m_wjcGridXlsx` is a value being used where a namespace is expected.

The simple, and idiomatic solution is to import the type and use it.

```
import {XlsxFormatItemEventArgs} from 'wijmo/wijmo.grid.xlsx';

export class ChildComponent {
  _exportFormatItem(args: XlsxFormatItemEventArgs) {}
}
```

This is entirely unrelated to inheritance and classes and properties. It just importing a type from a module so we can use it to annotate a value, in this case the parameter `args`.

If you prefer, you can use a module namespace import and reference the type qualified by the namespace alias you create in the import statement.

```
import * as wijmo from 'wijmo/wijmo.grid.xlsx';

export class ChildComponent {
  _exportFormatItem(args: wijmo.XlsxFormatItemEventArgs) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a value on the instance of the parent class as a type.
You'll either need to make the property statatic and use typeof to grab the type, or import the type itself into the child class.

Note that the argument value might be passed from the parent class, but the type information doesn't need to come via the parent class.

Comment: This is quite true, but `typeof` won't recover the namespaceness of the imported binding so one can't access the `XlsxFormatItemEventArgs` type using it.

Comment: I see, but won't it be able to infer the correct type by looking at the parent? Assuming it's a static property. Of course, that's less ideal than the import since they won't be able to reference the actual type, but type wise it should be correct, no?

Comment: Given a module, **a.ts**, containing `export type T = {}; export const v = 1;`, and a module, **b.ts**, containing `import * as a from './a';` const a_ = a;`. You can access the _type of_ the exported _value_ `v` via `typeof a_['v']`, but not the _type_ `T`. In other words, in **b.ts**, `a` module namespace qualifying both the types and values exported by **a.ts**, but `a_` is just the value aspect of `a`.

Comment: Okay, so that's where you end up with something like a plain object as the type inside of b, rather than the type T (even though the plain object and T would match the same shape)?

Comment: It has to do with the difference between the type space and the value space. A value names live in the value space and all members of a value are themselves values. A type names live in the type space and all members of a type are themselves types. Namespaces live in both spaces. The members of a namespace can be either types or values. Namespaces are created by constructs such as `namespace ns {}` and `import * as ns`.